# Create table on the fly with Insert Into

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is this possible?  I got a big .sql file full of Insert Into statements without the database schema.  Can I just create table on the fly?

Here is an example:

```
INSERT INTO [g_fuel_site] ([SiteID], ... ,[EMVEnabled])
  VALUES('Sep 23 2011 3:05:51:000PM', ... ,0)
```

EDIT:  There is no tables!  The script assumed I do!

Comment: @Bernie why not also fix the formatting while you're editing the tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aaron beat me by 20 seconds. 
For an example change the first insert from:

```
INSERT INTO [g_fuel_site] ([SiteID],[CurrentOperatingLevelID],[CurrentPriceBookID],  [NumberFuelSaleBuffers],[LinearUnitOfMeasure],[VolumeUnitOfMeasure],[PreAuthAllowed],[StackedSalesAllowed],[MaxLiveDispensers],[AllowedZeroPPUs],[MaxPPU],[MinPPU],[InitialConfigDone],[DispenserOptionModeID],[GenAuthEnabled],[PendingPriceBookID],[AllowPresetWithHandleUp],[UseFixedGradeName],[UseFixedServiceLevelName],[UseFixedGradeProductCodes],[TokenAttendantRcptCtl],[TokenAttendantNtwrkRcptCtl],[TokenAttendantPrpayRcptCtl],[RunAttendantInBufferedMode],[AllowAttendantBalanceQuery],[TokenOrStandardOperation],[TokenPrefix],[EnablePostPayLimit],[PostPayLimit],[EMVEnabled])VALUES('Sep 23 2011  3:05:51:000PM',1,1,2,'CM','L',1,1,12,0,9.9990,0.7500,1,1,1,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,'',0,100.0000,0)
```

to be:

```
SELECT 
'Sep 23 2011  3:05:51:000PM' [SiteID],
1 [CurrentOperatingLevelID],
1 [CurrentPriceBookID],
2 [NumberFuelSaleBuffers],
'CM' [LinearUnitOfMeasure],
'L' [VolumeUnitOfMeasure],
1 [PreAuthAllowed],
1 [StackedSalesAllowed],
12 [MaxLiveDispensers],
0 [AllowedZeroPPUs],
9.9990 [MaxPPU],
0.7500 [MinPPU],
1 [InitialConfigDone],
1 [DispenserOptionModeID],
1 [GenAuthEnabled],
2 [PendingPriceBookID],
1 [AllowPresetWithHandleUp],
0 [UseFixedGradeName],
0 [UseFixedServiceLevelName],
0 [UseFixedGradeProductCodes],
0 [TokenAttendantRcptCtl],
0 [TokenAttendantNtwrkRcptCtl],
0 [TokenAttendantPrpayRcptCtl],
0 [RunAttendantInBufferedMode],
0 [AllowAttendantBalanceQuery],
0 [TokenOrStandardOperation],
'' [TokenPrefix],
0 [EnablePostPayLimit],
100.0000 [PostPayLimit],
0 [EMVEnabled]
INTO g_fuel_site
```

After this the table will exist. It just infers column types, and will only work if the first select into contains all the columns that later inserts expect.

Comment: Holy crap, did you type all that out by hand?  Seem like so much work, I don't think I can use replace to get the format right, which mean I have to do convert the formatting manually.

Comment: Nah, used notepad++ and a regex find and replace to replace the commas with comma and newline. Then alt select to copy and paste all the values in front of the column names.

Comment: If the inserts are all into the same table, then you only have to change the first one.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not.  There is about 30 tables.  I will accept this as the answer.  I don't think I want to spend the time doing it up though, it's not mandatory for me.  I just thought it would be neat if it was possible and quick.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the first one (and only the first one) to `SELECT INTO`, yes. Assuming the first `INSERT` has correctly deducible data types. Note that it won't magically create keys, indexes, constraints, computed columns, etc. for you.

However your example also includes a leading `DELETE`, which leads me to believe the table already exists. `DELETE` deletes all of the rows from the table, it doesn't drop the table. If the table doesn't exist, then your script should (a) check if it exists before running a delete and (b) run the first command a `SELECT INTO` so that it creates it. However you will probably want to define data types (I also find it hard to believe that `SiteID` is a `DATETIME`).

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.g_fuel_site') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
  DELETE g_fuel_site;
END
ELSE
BEGIN 
  SELECT SiteID = CONVERT(INT, 1), ... 
    INTO dbo.g_fuel_site 
    WHERE 1 = 0; -- creates table but with 0 rows
END

INSERT dbo.g_fuel_site(SiteID, ...) VALUES(...); -- first row
INSERT ...          
INSERT ...
```

Comment: Right because you have to do more to create a SELECT INTO statement than just swap out the word INSERT.

Comment: The script assume I had the table schema, I do not.

Comment: @YongkeBillYu then no, you can't. In order to "create a table on the fly" you need to at least know what to call the columns. And since the `INSERT` you posted in the question has the column names, you must be able to get at them somehow.

Comment: The column name is in the INSERT INTO statement ([SiteID], ... ,[EMVEnabled])

Comment: @YongkeBillYu I understand that. But SQL Server can't magically create a table from an INSERT statement in a .sql file. You'd have to parse it programmatically.